# Remove space next to h1

Tags: html, css

I've created this html&css code and now i'm just stuck for some reason. It won't let me remove the space next to my h1. I've tried a lot but nothing seems to work. oops.

```css
 
.h1-banner {
 font-size: 60px;
 border: 2px solid #2B75A3;
 background-color: #2B75A3;
}
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 50vh;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom:0;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #3BB1E5;
}
```

```html
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="h1-banner">Title</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: what space? make a fiddle:)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs All markup is required to be placed here within her question: [mcve] not a fiddle.

Comment: That’s not “space”, that is simply how wide a h1 as a block element is by default (full width of the container element). If you want it to be as wide as the text only, then make it inline or inline-block.

Comment: @Rob true as that may be, it's hard to just know what it renders with above code vs. what's expected

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs That's why SO has the ability to create snippets here and a fiddle isn't necessary.

Comment: @Rob True true, and that's all I meant - didn't realise it was part of native SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<h1>` per definition is a block level element. Hence, it covers the whole (horizontal) space as given.

You could simply change it to `display: inline-block;`. Then it only expands as much as needed per its content. Some minor additions of some padding might be useful as well:

```css
.h1-banner {
 font-size: 60px;
 border: 2px solid #2B75A3;
 background-color: #2B75A3;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.1em 1em;
}
.jumbotron {
 background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 height: 50vh;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom:0;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #3BB1E5;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
     <div class="container">
      <h1 class="h1-banner">Title</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
```